# Java- how to set a specific value in a drop list based on the value stored in database in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, drop-down-menu, default

i have a drop box with static values and i i have made a EDIT.jsp page now which will show the values i stored in the database and i want them to be shown in  a drop list as a default value consider there are 4 elements

```
    <select name="language">
  <option value="1">c++</option>
  <option value="2">php</option>
  <option value="3">.net</option>
  <option value="4">java</option>
```

i want if the value in the database table is 3 then when the page loads the default value should be as shown in the drop list be

```
     <select name="language">
  <option value="3">.net</option>
  <option value="1">c++</option>
  <option value="2">php</option>
  <option value="4">java</option>
```

and i can't use jquery in this...i want a solution preferably in java 
i tried using value attribute and javascript but it sis nt work...i am new to java so i could nt figute out how to pass java scriplets in javascript if they r possible...i am making a Online examination system for my 2nd year engineering project

please help!!

Comment: show us the backend code

Comment: Do you want to say that the first value should be the value in the database ?

Comment: How are you getting the data from the database to the jsp? Without knowing what you already have it's going to be kinda hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use selected attribute of option tag.

get the value which is stored in the database and, put them in select box

```
<c:if test={1 is selected}>
    <option value = "1" selected="selected">c++</option>
</c:if>

<c:if test={2 is selected}>
    <option value = "2" selected="selected">java</option>
</c:if>

<c:if test={3 is selected}>
    <option value = "3" selected="selected">php</option>
</c:if>

<c:if test={4 is selected}>
    <option value = "4" selected="selected">.net</option>
</c:if>
```

Comment: ok so u eman to say i compare the values i got in the result set with all the values of drop list and based on the condition i set the value....

Comment: just for understanding and elarning sake is their any otehr approach also using scripts or another code...

Comment: yes, because you dont know which one is selected in database to put directly selected attribute, so put it for all and enable if it is in database.

Comment: you have to get the value to know which one is selected in database, and you have to put that in jsp.

Comment: @bhavik
sir i am trying to set the value in teh database a s default value so in case teh user does not check all values and clicks submit button the value remains same as the value default will be the selected one then....

Comment: @chadNC....sir i am getting value in jsp in a result set using basic jdbc...with backend as MS SQL server...(if its needed)

Comment: thank you soo much @ramesh K sir...i will try the code and let you know...it seems it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

For whatever option you want to be selected by default, change it as

```
<option value="3" SELECTED >.net</option>
```

Note : the SELECTED attribute of  tag will select the option by default.